# Chrome Debugger Breakpoint not Working

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Can't seem to find an answer as to why `debugger;` isn't working.

```
        RSVP.aggregate([{
            $lookup: {
                from: "users", // collection name in db
                localField: "userId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "user"
            }
        }
        ]).exec( (err, rsvpList) => {
            if (err) throw err("Mongoose aggregate failed to join rsvps to users: " + err);
            console.log('rsvp: ' + rsvpList[0].user.toString());
            debugger;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was because I was using node.js.  I was able to download and install the nodejs inspection manager Chrome and get it working.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj

Comment: Alternatively, you can debug node in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: or just open chrome://inspect/ you will find all running processes